gulp-html-replace: not replacing css block but replaces js block
Some weird thing is happening which I can't wrap my head around...
I have a gulp script that first starts with bundling js and css.
Then I have another script that takes 1 handlebars file (the main layout) that should use the bundled js and css. It takes it from the app folder and has the destination set to the dist folder.
Code
Handlebars file (main.hbs)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- build:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/font-awesome.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:lib_js -->
    <script src="/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/lib/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- body content here -->
</body>


</html>

Gulp tasks/functions
const _lib_JS_bundle = function() {

  const toReturn = src([ // Order is important!
      'app/public/js/lib/jquery*.js', // JQuery always first
      'app/public/js/lib/bootstrap*.js', // Then bootstrap
      'app/public/js/lib/moment*.js', // Then ...
      'app/public/js/lib/datatables*.js',
      'app/public/js/lib/*.js', // Any other file!
      '!app/public/js/lib/*owasp*.js' // EXCLUDE owasp strength tests... Only required on some pages!
    ])
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js')) // Concatenate read files; resulting file shall be bundle.js
    .pipe(dest(`${config.destination.directory}/js/lib/`)); // Write to disk

    return toReturn;
}


const _css_bundle = function() {

  const toReturn = src([ // Order is important!
    'app/public/css/lib/bootstrap*.css', // Bootstrap first
    'app/public/css/lib/datatables*.css',
    'app/public/css/lib/*.css',
    'app/public/css/*.css', // Custom CSS last
  ])
    .pipe(concat('bundle.css')) // Concatenate into bundle.css
    .pipe(dest(`${config.destination.directory}/css/`)); // Write to disk
    

    return toReturn;
}

const _updateMainLayoutBundleRefs = function(){

  const toReturn = src('app/views/layouts/main.hbs') // HTML HEAD is defined in main.hbs
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'lib_js': '/js/lib/bundle.js', // Search for block called 'lib_js' and update reference
        'css':'/css/bundle.css' // Search for block called 'css' and update reference
      }, {
        keepUnassigned: true, // Keep other blocks (css, ...)
        keepBlockTags: true // Keep other blocks (css, ...)
    }))
    .pipe(dest(`${config.destination.directory}/views/layouts/`)); // Write

    return toReturn;
}



Current result
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- build:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/font-awesome.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/lib/datatables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:lib_js -->
    <script src="/js/lib/bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- body content here -->
</body>


</html>

Expected result
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <!-- build:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bundle.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:lib_js -->
    <script src="/js/lib/bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    
</head>
<body>
    <!-- body content here -->
</body>


</html>

Extra information
I can confirm that the bundling works. Both bundle.js and bundle.css are in the destination directory.
The tasks are currently ran manually in a sequential order.
